How to cross-compile Rust-based Python wheel
I want to create a Python wheel that will run on both Windows and Linux (x86_64 and possibly ARM). I want to write the data processing code in Rust and have Python call the Rust code, so I am going to need to have different wheels for each target.
I can use maturin to create Python wheels that make calls to Rust. I can also use cargo to perform cross compilation of Rust code.
I am building this inside an environment where I don’t have access to GitHub Actions so I can’t easily run CI build actions on multiple OSes.
Can I create multiple Python wheels on a Linux build server that target different OSes and if so, how do I do this?

Python build tools are rather bad at cross-compiling and probably will never improve because VMs/containers with foreign architectures are now pervasive. So for every architecture you want to target use a VM or a container with the target architecture.

See documentation on cross-compiling with maturin.
